# Is there a way I can update some specific data I saved in a text file without changing the whole text file. Data in binary only

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, pickle, file-handling

(I AM NEW TO PYTHON PROGRAMMING)

I am using pickle to save some data into a text file in binary and save it in the format:
**username firstname lastname password** this task is completed successfully but when I try to use the second code **reset_password()** I am unable to edit a specified data like *I only want to change the first name, username or password* for a specific user saved in the text file. I want the whole data to be always saved in binary in the txt file, when I dump the changed password the whole text file is empty and only password is written **OR** I am unable to save the new dictionary into the file in binary format.

**CAN ANYONE GUIDE ME THROUGH THIS PLEASE**

```
def create_user():  # create New User
important_import = open("uandp", "ab")
users = []
birthday = input("Enter your date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY) ", )
day, month, year = birthday.split("/")
password = int(input("Enter Password:"))
first_name = input("Enter your first name:")
last_name = input("Enter your last name:")
users.append(f"{day}{month}{year} {first_name} {last_name} {password}\n")
pickle.dump(users, important_import)
important_import.close()
print(f"Person Added to the List :{first_name} {last_name}")
```

> The CODE for obtaining data from the binary text file and to change password in the file.

```
def reset_password():  # reset password
user_name0 = int(input("Enter Username:"))
new_password = int(input("Enter New Password (Max 10 characters allowed): "))
confirm_new_password = int(input("Reenter New Password (Max 10 characters allowed): "))
measuring_length_of_password = str(new_password)
converting_into_string = str(user_name0)
tf = 0
blank_for_read_first_name = {}
blank_for_read_last_name = {}
blank_for_read_password = {}
new_dictionary = {}
with open('uandp', 'rb') as binary_code:
    non_binary_code = pickle.load(binary_code)
    converted_list_into_dictionary = dict(non_binary_code)
    print(converted_list_into_dictionary)
    for line in non_binary_code:
        splitLine = line.split()
        blank_for_read_password[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[3:])
        blank_for_read_first_name[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[1:-2])
        blank_for_read_last_name[int(splitLine[0])] = ",".join(splitLine[2:-1])
        binary_code.close()
        for parts in ["measuring_length_of_password"]:
            new_dictionary[user_name0] = eval(parts)
        reopening_file = open('uandp', 'wb')
        if new_password == confirm_new_password and len(measuring_length_of_password) <= 10:
            converted_list_into_dictionary.update(new_dictionary)
            pickle.dump(converted_list_into_dictionary, reopening_file)
            tf = 1
        reopening_file.close()
if tf == 0:
    print("No User Found!")
else:
    print("Password Changed Successfully!")
```

Comment: You're looking for a database, not a file.  You cannot simply change the middle of a file.   Databases are designed for permanent storage of key/value pairs, and for changing the values of the keys.

Comment: If you want to update dome data in middle of  file with records and this size of a record is not fixed (which is your case), you have to rewrite the full file when you modify one record.

Comment: Should I simply turn to database ? instead of text files

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.